# (N)Hibernate "session-per-application" considered evil for specific use case?

Tags: java, hibernate, nhibernate, orm, transactions

Ok, everyone knows that a global session-per-application with (N)Hibernate is discouraged. BUT I have a very specific, apparently non-standard use case for which it seems to be the ideal solution.

To sum it up, my (server) application basically has all of its persistent data constantly in-memory and never queries the database for normal operation. The only reason for a database in the first place is so that the data survives the lifetime of the process. I only want to query the database on application startup to fetch everything into memory. The database is only about 5-10 MB realistically.

Now the problem is that if I follow the advice that sessions must be short lived, I have to merge() all my data for every business transaction or somehow manually track all changes, instead of taking advantage of NHibernate's automatic change tracking. This makes persistence very difficult to implement without causing a lot of performance overhead.

So my question is whether there are any reasons why I shouldn't use a global session for this particular use case?

Common arguments against global sessions that I know of:

1. First level cache will be filled with entire database over time
   => I don't mind that, since I actually *want* to have all data in memory!
2. Stale data and concurrency problems
   => My application is designed so that all code that can access or modify persistent data must be single threaded (a deliberate design choice), and it is the only application that can write to the database. So this shouldn't be a problem.
3. Session gets corrupted if it throws an exception (e.g. DB timeout)
   => That's the only real problem I can see, but can be solved by discarding the session, creating a new one and refreshing all data. Expensive, but exceptions should be very rare and can only be caused either by a major bug or major infrastructure problems, which should both be solved ASAP.

So I believe there is no reason why I shouldn't use a global session *for my particular use case*. Or is there something important that I'm missing?

*Update 1: It's a server application*

*Update 2: This doesn't imply a long-lived global transactions. Transactions would still be short-lived - one long-lived session, many short-lived transactions.*

Comment: Is this a desktop application?

Comment: @dotjoe No, it's a server application. I'm updating the question to add that bit of information.

Comment: server application that is single threaded?

Comment: @dotjoe I didn't say that. I said that _all code that can access or modify persistent data must be single threaded_.

Comment: so that single threaded code to write data...does that use a single transaction for the entire lifetime of the app and commits it at the end?

Comment: No. I want to use an explicit transaction for every logical "work item". That means, one session, many transactions.

Comment: All code that can access or modify persistent data being single threaded is not enough. Is that code accessing the session object on the same single thread every time?

Comment: Yes, of course. Wouldn't make any sense otherwise. Besides, sharing a session across multiple threads would _always_ be an _extremely_ stupid beginner's mistake - and I'm not _that_ dumb.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you *fan-in* all transactions coming from multiple threads to a single dedicated back-end thread executor, then you can indeed use a single Session per application.

Exceptions can be triggered by lock timeouts, server crashes or constraint violations, so retreating the backing Session would lead to discarding all the first-level cache entries, which is bad for your use case. In this case, you will have to re-fetch everything from the DB and because you use a single back-end thread, all the other client threads will be blocked, which is unconvincing.

I would advise you using the [second-level cache instead](http://vladmihalcea.com/how-does-hibernate-store-second-level-cache-entries/). You can configure the 2LC provider to stre evryhting in-memory, instead of overflowing to the disk. You can load all the data in 2nd level cache when the application starts and use a [NONSTRICT_READ_WRITE Cache Concurrency Strategy](http://vladmihalcea.com/how-does-hibernate-nonstrict_read_write-cacheconcurrencystrategy-work/) to speed-up writes (Concurrency issues aren't a problem for you anyway).

You need to make sure you use [2NL caching for collections too](http://vladmihalcea.com/how-does-hibernate-collection-cache-work/).

The simplest design is to use a session-per-request as the Session is kinda lightweight anyway and it will fetch data from the in-memory 2LC anyway.

You need to run some performance tests to see if it's worth to reusing a Session, instead of creating a new one on every single transaction. You might find out that this process is not your bottleneck anyway and you shouldn't do any optimization without a real proof.

Another reason for discarding the session is that most database-related exceptions are not recoverable anyway. If the server gets down or the current request throws a constraint violation, retying it won't fix anything anyway.

Comment: _If you fan-in all transactions coming from multiple threads to a single dedicated back-end thread executor, then you can indeed use a single Session per application._

Yes, that is basically what I'm doing.

The second level cache approach occurred to me as well. But the problem here is how to track changes during transactions for persistence. I'd have to attach _all_ objects to the new session at the start of each transaction, right? Even if I use the 2LC and thus don't have to hit the DB for that, I'd still have the overhead of hydrating all persistent objects again.

Comment: You still use a Session, even when you employ the 2LC. The dirty checking mechanism keeps track of all changes and indeed the entities must be rehydration from the 2LC into the 1LC upon loading entities, but only a performance test must prove if that's really an issue for you. The rehydration is like taking an array of values and recreating an associated object for it and because this happens in-memory, it only takes tens or hundreds of nanoseconds.

Comment: Ok, I see where you are going now. You are suggesting to always re-fetch all data that is needed for the current transaction from the 2LC, rather than attaching existing entity objects to the new session. Could be worth a try. I'm still anxious about the overhead that creates. AFAIK the 2LC doesn't store the actual entity objects but just their property values in a key-value-store - so this means the session would always have create and hydrate new objects when fetching from the 2LC, right?
EDIT: Didn't see your comment before adding mine, already answers my question.

Comment: I'll investigate that approach and probably mark this as accepted in a couple of days - thanks!

Comment: It's worth trying it out.

Comment: Ok, one more thing I'm anxious about: Doesn't the collection cache expire when I add / remove something, just like the query cache, causing a DB hit when I load the collection again?

Comment: You are right, that's for consistency. If it's against your design, you can use a separate cache, like memcached. In this case you need to update both the cache and the DB yourself on every transaction.

Comment: Your requirements sound like you need a persisted in-memory DB, like [MemSQL](http://www.memsql.com/)

Comment: Well, a seperate cache sounds like I'm back to square one, having to track changes myself. As for in-memory DB: Would be an interesting approach, but not really an option (for non-technical reasons :-( )

Comment: All answers provided useful insight, but since this was the first one, I'll award you the bounty.

Comment: Thanks. What was the final design decision you've taken?

Comment: Well, for _future_ projects with similar requirements, I'll go a completely different approach: http://martinfowler.com/eaaDev/EventSourcing.html

I wanted to introduce this approach to the current project as well, but the team decided against it. Basically, we are using a session per transaction, but keep all data in memory, track changes on it ourselves and merge() changed objects. I hope this doesn't cause too much performance overhead -- in a few weeks we'll see.

Answer (score 4):

One of the potential disadvantages I can see is that dirty check may take a long time to execute; you will have to use bytecode instrumentation mode to solve this issue.

Also, the serialized access to the server may affect performance much more than recreating the objects from the second-level cache (object creation is very fast in modern JVMs). This is even true in single-user applications (the user may trigger a long-runnig operation on one screen and want to do something else on the other, or the server may trigger a scheduled operation thus blocking the user to access the server until the operation is done).

Thirdly, rearchitecturing your approach may be hard later if the need arises to execute concurrent requests after all.

Next, you will not avoid going to the database when executing queries anyway.

Finally, extended session is a Hibernate feature that is not used as common as the classic session-per-request pattern. Although Hibernate is a good piece of software, it is also complex and thus has many bugs. I would expect more bugs and weaker community support/documentation related to less-used features (as in every other framework).

So my suggestion is to use the second-level cache and to handle the concurrency issues using optimistic/pessimistic locks depending on the use cases. You can enable caching of all entities by default by using `DISABLE_SELECTIVE` or `ALL` shared cache mode, as described in the [docs](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/core/manual/en-US/html/performance.html#performance-cache).

Comment: _Also, the serialized access to the server may affect performance much more than recreating the objects from the second-level cache_

=> That's somewhat besides the point. We don't "de-parallelize" to avoid object creation (I know that this is cheap), but because we believe that we can actually achieve much less latency and better throughput with that design by avoiding the difficulties associated with concurrency. The idea was partly inspired by LMAX => see http://martinfowler.com/articles/lmax.html

[continued]

Comment: _Next, you will not avoid going to the database when executing queries anyway._ => Well, the goal is to completely avoid queries, except at application startup. Like I said, the database is only needed to persist the application state so we can continue where we left off after restarting the process.

_I would expect more bugs [...]_ => That's pretty much the point I'm worried about most :-(

[continued]

Comment: _So my suggestion is to use the second-level cache_ => That's something I have been thinking about - see the discussion about Vlad's answer. The problem is not the overhead for object hydration, but that collection caches are expired rather than updated when adding / removing objects, which for our application will lead to constantly querying the DB through lazy loading - putting us back to square one.

Comment: **Edited comment** _"but that collection caches are expired rather than updated when adding / removing objects"_ That's true. But, when you update things, you will go to the db to persist changes anyway. _"the goal is to completely avoid queries"_ That means you access objects always by id?

Comment: _But, when you update things, you will go to the db to persist changes anyway._ Yes, but I only want to hit the DB for writing, I don't want to have to hit it _again_ to load data which I already know to be up-to-date in memory.
_That means you access objects always by id?_ I want to access the objects in-memory, with whatever data structures I see fit for that.

Answer (score 2):

The reasons for not using global session can be summarized as below:

*** First level cache:** You have to understand. First level cache is not just about memory. A consequence of first level cache is when ever an object is saved or delete or queried, (n)hibernate has to ensure that prior to this event, the database has to be in a consistent state with your memory. That is flushing. However, (n)hibernate has one unique feature, that is called Transparent persistence. Unlike other ORM's like entity framework, you don't have track what is dirty. NHiberante does that for you. But the way it works is somewhat costly. It compares all previous object states with the new ones and try to detect what has change. So if your first level cache is full of entities the performance will degrade. This problem can be circumvented in two ways:

1-) using session.Flush(); session.Clear();

2-) using stateless session.

In the first case all your pending changes go to database. After that you can safely clear the session. **However keeps the data in memory even if your clear the session until the transaction is disposed.** That is due to the possibility that you can vote the transaction to be rejected at the end. (Can give more info on this if requested)

Second case, for stateless session, (n) hibernate behaves like a micro ORM. There is no tracking. It is lightweight but gives you more responsibility.

*** Session related exceptions:** Another valid reason for not using application wide session is, whenever an exception occurs related to session or database (such as unique constraint violation) then your session is doomed. You cannot work with it any more because it is in inconsistent state with the database. So your global session has to be renewed and this brings more complication.

*** Thread Safety:**  Neither session nor any ADO.NET construct is thread safe. If you use a global session object along with multiple threads, you have to ensure some sort of thread safety. That can be very very difficult.

Comment: While all your points are valid, they only partially apply to my problem.

_However keeps the data in memory ..._ yes, but I already explained that I don't mind that in my use case.

_Thread Safety ..._ I know the session is not thread safe, but like I explained, I am avoiding that problem by dispatching all read/write operations on persistent data to a single thread. So again, does not apply to my use case.

_Session related exceptions_: That is a problem I'd have to deal with in some way, but I already considered that.

_Dirty checking_: That earns you the upvote, I hadn't considered that.